# Request Method GET is Not Supported in the Rest API

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I am working on a java springboot project along with the rest api, I need to pass parameter in one of the uri and I am getting "request method GET not supported" error when I use this

```
  //@GetMapping("logs/date?from={from}&to={to}")
  @RequestMapping(value="logs/date?from={from}&to={to}",method=RequestMethod.Get)
  public list getLogs(@RequestParam(value="from") String from,@RequestParam("to") String to)){....}
```

It works correctly when I use

```
  @RequestMapping(value="logs/date/from={from}&to={to}",method=RequestMethod.Get)
   public list getLogs(@PathVariable(value="from") String from,@PathVariable("to") String to)){....}
```

but I need the url to have "?" before passing the parameter so when I replace

```
  @RequestMapping(value="logs/date/from={from}&to={to}",method=RequestMethod.Get)
```

with this

```
  @RequestMapping(value="logs/date?from={from}&to={to}",method=RequestMethod.Get)
```

I get the GET method not supported error.

Comment: I am getting "no message available for 'logs/date/2016-03-03/2016-03-30' " error after not specifying the param in the value mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way of writing the RequestMapping value is incorrect. You need not write `from={from}&to={to}` in the `value` field. The correct way is below:

`@RequestMapping(value="/logs/date",method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getLogs(@RequestParam(value="from") String from,@RequestParam("to") String to)){....}`

Now you may make the API call with the URL

`http://localhost:8080/log/date?from=fromText&to=toText`

Comment: It works now thank you Madhu, I was sending the parameter in a wrong manner in the url

Comment: Cheers @varun :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way you should do it.

You do this in case of `@PathVariable` but for request parameters should be defined from frontend itself.

So do not do this in controller or backend.

Comment: As of now I am using postman to check the uri so when I use the "logs/date?" as value attribute in request mapping and I am sending the from and to dates as json from the postman I am getting an error 'failed to convert value of string to long'for input "\date\"